# Default gateway has the same IP as the DHCP Server

Tags: dhcp, gateway, dhcp-server

Just out of curiosity, Is it normal for a default gateway to have the same IP as the DHCP server? I am running windows server with no roles installed, My IPs are dynamically allocated by the DHCP trough my router I think. Is it normal for this to happen?

Comment: It’s normal, especially with all-in-one home routers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if the DHCP server IS your default gateway, otherwise, you'll run into problems.  The fact that you're on the internet suggests that it is the same, so yeah, it's normal.